# Linear Algebra and probability

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

For a linear system $(m=4, n=2)$ made up of random numbers, what is the probability,
roughly, that the system has one solution?

For a linear system with $m=n=2$ made up of random numbers, what is the probability,
roughly, that the system has no solution?

For second question I think probability is close to $1$ and for first I think it is $0$. Is it correct?

Comment: Are you talking about a system of $n$ linear equations in $m$ variables?

Comment: Yes system of linear equation with m rows n columns @almagest

Comment: Homogeneous or non-homogeneous systems? (Are the numbers on the RHS zeroes, or are they chosen randomly, too?) Also it might be useful to specify the field.

Comment: system is totally random so system may not be homogeneous so RHS is also random? If possible case by case? @MartinSleziak

Comment: This could be useful for square real matrices: [Probability that a determinant is equal to zero.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2067811)

Comment: You need to be more precise about 'random'.  For instance do you mean random integers chosen uniformly from some range (and if so what range)? Or do you mean random real numbers chosen uniformly from a range?  Or some other distribution?

Comment: What's your probability distribution? There's probably no good theory for general entry distributions.

Comment: Is it true that any two planes embedded in $x-y-z$ space will intersect in a straight line? @MartinSleziak

Comment: that need not be true, the two planes can be parallel to each other and be distinct. I agree with the comments that the word 'random' need clarification.